# How to use plot with different color under 3 conditions?

Tags: r, if-statement, plot

How can I use `plot` in R with different colors under 3 conditions? like x>10, x>20, x>30

Answer (score 0):

You may use `cut()` to identify the bins.

```
i <- cut(y, c(min(y), 10, 20, 30, max(y)), include.lowest=T)
id <- levels(i)
```

Then, on an empty `plot` use `points` in an `lapply`.

```
plot(y, type="n")
lapply(seq(id), function(v) 
  points(which(i == id[v]), y[i == id[v]], col=v)
)
```

[image]

#### Data

```
set.seed(42)
y <- sample(1:40, 200, replace=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new categorical variable and add it to your data.frame. As in:

```
iris2<-iris%>%mutate(Petal.Width_categorical=factor(case_when(Petal.Width<1 ~ 'small',
                                                Petal.Width>=1 & Petal.Width<2 ~ 'medium',
                                                Petal.Width>=2 ~ 'large')))
```

Than just call your plot with a `col` argument mapped to that variable:

```
with(iris2, plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, col=Petal.Width_categorical))
```

[iris2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjm8W.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse`with the `col` argument:

```
plot(x, col = ifelse(x <=10, "red",
                     ifelse(x > 10 & x <=20, "orange", "lawngreen")))
```

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(1:40, 1000, replace = T)
```

[image]